# PupeteerSharp - Feature For Browser Lock

Tags: puppeteer-sharp

I am trying to scrape hyperlinks that are initiated by JS. The problem is when I click on items such as  tags, the browser navigates away in the "Request" event. Then all of the following elements error out when clicking because the page is no longer there. Is there a way to prevent the page from navigating away?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't get quite the idea. If you click on a link you will navigate to another page. Maybe what you want to do is grabbing all the hrefs values and then navigate to all those URLs?

Comment: I do not want to navigate at all.  I only want to scrape for links.  Anchors <a> are not a problem.  I need links that are generated via JS.  For example clicking on a <div> that fires some JS to generate a link and then navigates.

Comment: Could you share some code example? it's not clear what you are asking for.

Comment: I appreciate your helping.  I do not have an example as I am looking for code to do this.   Imagine a web page with a JavaScript based menu.  On click of the items executes some JS and then navigates to a URL.   I need to click on all the menu items to get all of the URLs.  The problem is that the navigate occurs after the first click.  Therefore all of the other clicks are invalid.  I need the page to stay in place while I go thorough all of the clicks.